# Webpack 4 dynamic import resulting in TypeError: [object Module] is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, sweetalert2

I can’t figure out what i’m doing wrong here - trying to dynamically import sweetalert2 only when needed after clicking on an element. onclick calls this function:

```
  function triggerForm() {
    import ('sweetalert2' /* webpackChunkName: "sweetalert2" */)
      .then( Swal => {
        Swal.fire({
         // alert stuff
        })
      })
      .catch( error => console.error(error) )
  }
```

I’m getting `TypeError: [object Module] is not a constructor` on the `Swal.fire` line. Regular import works fine.

webpack output config:

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: config.publicPath,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out default imports don't play nice anymore. So we have to specifically assign the default like so:

```
  function triggerForm() {
    import ('sweetalert2' /* webpackChunkName: "sweetalert2" */)
      .then( ({ default: Swal }) => {
        Swal.fire({
         // alert stuff
        })
      })
      .catch( error => console.error(error) )
  }
```

Notice, specifically, the `.then( ({ default: Swal }) => {` line above.